# Remove double margins for a single page?

Tags: margins, templates

I'm using the AIP template seen [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/aip/), I need to be able to make it so I can return to normal margins for a single page or two and then return back.  How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass[aip,jmp,reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\preprint{AIP/123-QED}
\title[Sample title]{Sample Title}
\thanks{Footnote to title of article.}
\author{A. Author}
 \altaffiliation[Also at ]{Physics Department, XYZ University.}
\author{B. Author}%
 \email{Second.Author@institution.edu.}
\affiliation{ 
Authors' institution and/or address
}%
\maketitle
\section{First Heading}
\blindtext
\subsection{A subsection}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give a little bit more information in form of a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html)?

Comment: Johannes_B I can't really give a minimal working example if I don't know where to begin can I?  If you would like to see the AIP template you can download it from the link.

Comment: Well, for starter, you could post the relevant part here, so everyone can test and compile directly. Furthermore, you can describe the desired result more precisely. I myself am not really sure i know what you want.

Comment: Could you define "normal margins"? Do you mean a single-column layout? If you would explain what exactly you're trying to achieve, maybe there are other solutions that are already available with the template?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear, yes I want to return to a single-column layout for a page.

Comment: I added an MWE to your question (if the peer review gets through). Please edit it, so we can reproduce what you want.

Comment: Johannes_B I don't see what you expect me to add to that, I don't know how to do what I want...

Comment: The above example gives me a single coulumn layout, you are requesting one. What did you do to make this happen?

Comment: Johannes_B that example is different to the template, and that example a single column on both pages, which is not what I want.

Comment: A minimal example could be just the `\documentclass[..]{revtex4-1}` line from the template, and a `document` environment with some text saying e.g. `this should be one-column` and `this text on the next page should be two-column`. It doesn't have to be a 'working' example in the sense that it does what you want, but it should be a 'starting' example, showing what you have, so you can point to what you want to change. Ideally a question should be self-contained, one shouldn't have to go to an external site to see the code.

Comment: It would also nice if you could rephrase your question and title, so that one doesn't have to read all the comments to find out what the question really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the possibility, that this is *not* what you want:

```
\documentclass[aip,jmp,reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\preprint{AIP/123-QED}
\title[Sample title]{Sample Title}
\thanks{Footnote to title of article.}
\author{A. Author}
\altaffiliation[Also at ]{Physics Department, XYZ University.}
\author{B. Author}%
\email{Second.Author@institution.edu.}
\affiliation{ 
    Authors' institution and/or address
}%
\maketitle
\newcommand{\testtext}{
\blindtext[2]
\subsection{A subsection}
\blindtext[3]\par
\blindtext[2]
}
\section{First Heading}
\blindtext
\subsection{A subsection}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\onecolumngrid
\section{onecolumn}
\testtext
\twocolumngrid
\section{twocolumn again}
\testtext
\clearpage
\onecolumngrid
\section{again onecolumn}
\testtext
\testtext
\clearpage
\twocolumngrid
\section{and again twocolumn}
\testtext
\end{document}
```

If you want to have something different, please state it clearly, so i can edit the answer accordingly.

Please be aware, that the `reprint` option is not what you are submitting to the journal. There *will* be differences in the actual output in the journal.